# Python split each element in list by '\n' and expand list from 2D to 3D

Tags: python, excel, list

I import an Excel worksheet with xlrd and store it into a 2d list(*data[row][col]*), and i want to split each element of the list by '\n'. Now i simply store it into another variable while in a for loop but is it possible to extend the list from 2d to 3d (*data[row][col][line]*)? If yes, how?

```
sh = book.sheet_by_index(0)
data = [[sh.cell_value(r, c) for c in range(sh.ncols)] for r in range(sh.nrows)]
for row in range(sh.nrows):
     for col in range (sh.ncols):
          data_lines=data[row][col].split("\n")
          *do stuff with variable*
```

I would benefit from expanding the list as i will be able to call specifically the line i need at any time, without iterating through it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `split` on each element:

```
li = [['a b c', 'd e f'], ['g h i', 'j k l']]
for index, line in enumerate(li):
    for inner_index, col in enumerate(line):
        li[index][inner_index] = li[index][inner_index].split()
print(li)
# [[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']], [['g', 'h', 'i'], ['j', 'k', 'l']]]
```

Comment: yeah, seems It's pretty simple, 
`data[row][col]=data[row][col].split("\n")` will do the trick!